how to copy formulas into a new sheet using office-script
I am new to office-script and I have tried to work on this issue with ChatGPT, but this was not helpful at all. :-(

I am trying to copy rows from one sheet to another with the code below, but this code does not include the formulas. I have no idea how to implement this into the code.

Within the next step I would need the same logic to move rows to a new sheet (including formulas).


A row can contain just data and formulas, some cells are empty at this stage. I had a problem with the format of the rows when I started. It always took over the format of the table header when the target table was empty. But that seems to be gone.
Some columns (different) are hidden in both sheets (target and source), but this was not a problem with the script below, it was only a problem with a solution from ChatGPT, which also did some strange things like insert the rows twice with overwriting existing rows. Strange AI! ;-)
Any help welcome!
here is the "copy code" so far:
/*
This script does the following:
Selects rows from the source table where the value in a column is equal to some value (FILTER_VALUE in the script).
Moves all selected rows into the target table in another worksheet.
Reapplies the relevant filters to the source table.
*/

function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {

    // You can change these names to match the data in your workbook.

    const TARGET_TABLE_NAME = "Start";

    const SOURCE_TABLE_NAME = "BasicInfo";




    // Select what will be moved between tables.

    const FILTER_COLUMN_INDEX = 5;

    const FILTER_VALUE = "to be processed";




    // Get the Table objects.

    let targetTable = workbook.getTable(TARGET_TABLE_NAME);

    let sourceTable = workbook.getTable(SOURCE_TABLE_NAME);




    // If either table is missing, report that information and stop the script.

    if (!targetTable || !sourceTable) {

        console.log(

            `Tables missing - Check to make sure both source (${TARGET_TABLE_NAME}) and target table (${SOURCE_TABLE_NAME}) are present before running the script. `

        );

        return;

    }




    // Save the filter criteria currently on the source table.

    const originalTableFilters = {};

    // For each table column, collect the filter criteria on that column.

    sourceTable.getColumns().forEach((column) => {

        let originalColumnFilter = column.getFilter().getCriteria();

        if (originalColumnFilter) {

            originalTableFilters[column.getName()] = originalColumnFilter;

        }

    });




    // Get all the data from the table.

    const sourceRange = sourceTable.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal();

    const dataRows: (

        | number

        | string

        | boolean

    )[][] = sourceTable.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getValues();




    // Create variables to hold the rows to be moved and their addresses.

    let rowsToMoveValues: (number | string | boolean)[][] = [];

    let rowAddressToRemove: string[] = [];




    // Get the data values from the source table.

    for (let i = 0; i < dataRows.length; i++) {

        if (dataRows[i][FILTER_COLUMN_INDEX] === FILTER_VALUE) {

            rowsToMoveValues.push(dataRows[i]);




            // Get the intersection between table address and the entire row where we found the match. This provides the address of the range to remove.

            let address = sourceRange

                .getIntersection(sourceRange.getCell(i, 0).getEntireRow())

                .getAddress();

            rowAddressToRemove.push(address);

        }

    }




    // If there are no data rows to process, end the script.

    if (rowsToMoveValues.length < 1) {

        console.log(

            "No rows selected from the source table match the filter criteria."

        );

        return;

    }




    console.log(`Adding ${rowsToMoveValues.length} rows to target table.`);




    // Insert rows at the end of target table.

    targetTable.addRows(-1, rowsToMoveValues);
 

    // Reapply the original filters.

    Object.keys(originalTableFilters).forEach((columnName) => {

        sourceTable

            .getColumnByName(columnName)

            .getFilter()

            .apply(originalTableFilters[columnName]);

    });

}


see above within my problem description

New code used to move rows to the next sheet and deleting the row in the source table (no rows will be moved and a filter is set at index 3 afer the script has run). I tried it with index 7 where just text is entered and no formula will generate the status and it worked, but with index 8 the script is not running as expected):

    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    const TARGET_TABLE_NAME = "Work";
    const SOURCE_TABLE_NAME = "Start";
    // Select what will be moved between tables.
    const FILTER_COLUMN_INDEX = 8;
    const FILTER_VALUE = "processed";

    let desTab = workbook.getTable(TARGET_TABLE_NAME);
    let srcTab = workbook.getTable(SOURCE_TABLE_NAME);
        
    if (desTab && srcTab) {
        // Clear auto filter on table srcTab
        srcTab.getAutoFilter().clearCriteria();
        // Apply checked items filter on table srcTab column Col5
        srcTab.getColumnById(FILTER_COLUMN_INDEX).getFilter().applyValuesFilter([FILTER_VALUE]);

        const filterRange = srcTab.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getSpecialCells(ExcelScript.SpecialCellType.visible);
        if (filterRange) {
            let anchorCell = desTab.getColumnById(1).getRange().getLastCell()
            if (anchorCell.getValue()) {
                // move to next line if not-blank
                anchorCell = anchorCell.getOffsetRange(1, 0)
            }
            anchorCell.copyFrom(filterRange);
            // Update formula
            desTab.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().replaceAll(`${SOURCE_TABLE_NAME}[`, "[", { completeMatch: false, matchCase: false });
            // Get range address
            const rangeList: string[] = filterRange.getAddress().split(",");
            // Remove data rows from source table
            for (let i = rangeList.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                let areaRange = srcTab.getWorksheet().getRange(rangeList[i]);
                areaRange.getEntireRow().delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up);
            }
            srcTab.getAutoFilter().clearCriteria();
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log("No data in filtered source table")
    }
    
}


How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


AI coding is a great starting point, but you definitely can't rely on it to produce flawless code. In your case, the AI is overcomplicating things.

function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    const TARGET_TABLE_NAME = "Start";
    const SOURCE_TABLE_NAME = "BasicInfo";
    // Select what will be moved between tables.
    const FILTER_COLUMN_INDEX = 5;
    const FILTER_VALUE = "to be processed";

    let desTab = workbook.getTable(TARGET_TABLE_NAME);
    let srcTab = workbook.getTable(SOURCE_TABLE_NAME);
    if (desTab && srcTab) {
        // Clear auto filter on table srcTab
        srcTab.getAutoFilter().clearCriteria();
        // Apply checked items filter on table srcTab column Col5
        srcTab.getColumnById(FILTER_COLUMN_INDEX).getFilter().applyValuesFilter([FILTER_VALUE]);

        const filterRange = srcTab.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getSpecialCells(ExcelScript.SpecialCellType.visible);
        if (filterRange) {
            let anchorCell = desTab.getColumnById(1).getRange().getLastCell()
            if (anchorCell.getValue()) {
                // move to next line if not-blank
                anchorCell = anchorCell.getOffsetRange(1, 0)
            }
            anchorCell.copyFrom(filterRange);
            // Update formula
            desTab.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().replaceAll(`${SOURCE_TABLE_NAME}[`, "[", { completeMatch: false, matchCase: false });
            // Get range address
            const rangeList: string[] = filterRange.getAddress().split(",");
            // Remove data rows from source table
            for (let i = rangeList.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                let areaRange = srcTab.getWorksheet().getRange(rangeList[i]);
                areaRange.getEntireRow().delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up);
            }
            srcTab.getAutoFilter().clearCriteria();
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log("No data in filtered source table")
    }
}


Thank you very much for your reply.
The script works so far. However, the formulas are changed so that they now check the cells in the source table. Since the changes and also the checks are to take place in the target table, I would need help here again!
In the second step, I would also need the same logic to move the rows to the next table (with formulas, as changes are also made there and these are to be checked). So in the second script the rows should be deleted in the source table after insertion in the target table.

I have found a solution for the table reference. I just had to adjust the formulas. So that now works as desired.
Now only the question about the move of a line is open.

After a few more tests I have to realise that the script does not work as I expected it to.
The rows are not added to the end of the target table but overwrite existing entries.
If the table is empty, an empty line appears at the top and the slicer function no longer works.

I've updated the code to fix the empty line and formulas. I haven't seen overwriting issue in testing. Please share screenshot or smaple data.

Thanks. I made some tests without the delete step (cause in the first step I want to copy the data from the Basic Information to the first worksheet and the basic information should stay intact for future use). That worked well.
Then I've tested the script with the delete step on the next sheet. Therefore I had to change the source and target table and also the index (to 8) and value ("processed") to be checked. The result was strange. There was a filter set at index 3 and no data where copied and or deleted.

I have to say, that the new filter value will be calculated by a formula like this: =IF(AND(G16=""; TODAY() >= $E$4);"overdue";IF(AND(G16=""; $E$4-TODAY()<=10);"deadline approaching";IF(G16<>""; "processed"; "open")))
Does this cause the problem with the filter setting?

It's difficult to answer your question without knowing your code. Please edit your post to share it.

original post updated with code I have used. It is working with columns where text is entered, but not where formulas generate the text.

There was a filter set at index 3  - I don't believe the issue arises from the code execution, as I have tested my code without any problems. The formula in Column 5 is =IF([@Col4]=1,"ready","to be processed"). Both filtering, copying, and deletion functions work correctly. You can comment out certain lines of code to test this further; for example, try commenting out clearCriteria and getEntireRow().delete to ensure the filtering functions as expected.

I've created a complete new table and tried with different indexes. I found out, that the new table is starting to count the index with 1 and not with 0 as the first script did (I thought a defined table allways starts with index 0. Any explanation for this?), therefore the script was checking the wrong column for the match and the clearCriteria was not executed. I've then changed the script to the correct index and it worked as expected. I've also added the clearCriteria for the case, that the search criteria was not within the column to restore/clear the filters.

sorry, to bother you again, but the script is not working when columns are hidden. Is there any chance to implement this into the script as well?

Please describe the detail of "not working".

if you hide column 3 and run the script it will not copy the information which is hidden.
I've used the AI to get this solved and got this code which I now only need to implement in the code from your script:
OK, can not enter code within the comment section.

I would like to share the final code for my problem and I want to thank taller for the help with this!
The code will move rows (with values and formulas) from one table to another, even if there are columns hidden. After the move process the original filter settings will be applied.
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    const TARGET_TABLE_NAME = "Work";
    const SOURCE_TABLE_NAME = "Start";
    // Select what will be moved between tables.
    const FILTER_COLUMN_INDEX = 9;
    const FILTER_VALUE = "processed";

    let desTab = workbook.getTable(TARGET_TABLE_NAME);
    let srcTab = workbook.getTable(SOURCE_TABLE_NAME);

    // Store hidden columns indices for both tables
    let hiddenSourceColumns: number[] = [];
    let hiddenTargetColumns: number[] = [];

    // Unhide hidden columns in the source table
    let sourceRange = srcTab.getRange();
    let sourceColumnsCount = sourceRange.getColumnCount();
    for (let index = 0; index < sourceColumnsCount; index++) {
        let columnRange = sourceRange.getColumn(index);
        if (columnRange.getEntireColumn().getHidden()) {
            hiddenSourceColumns.push(index);
            columnRange.getEntireColumn().setColumnHidden(false); // Unhide the column
        }
    }

    // Unhide hidden columns in the target table
    let targetRange = desTab.getRange();
    let targetColumnsCount = targetRange.getColumnCount();
    for (let index = 0; index < targetColumnsCount; index++) {
        let columnRange = targetRange.getColumn(index);
        if (columnRange.getEntireColumn().getHidden()) {
            hiddenTargetColumns.push(index);
            columnRange.getEntireColumn().setColumnHidden(false); // Unhide the column
        }
    }
    // Store original filters
    const originalTableFilters: { [key: string]: ExcelScript.FilterCriteria | undefined } = {};
    srcTab.getColumns().forEach((column: ExcelScript.TableColumn) => {
        let originalColumnFilter: ExcelScript.FilterCriteria = column.getFilter().getCriteria();
        if (originalColumnFilter) {
            originalTableFilters[column.getName()] = originalColumnFilter;
        }
    });

    if (desTab && srcTab) {
        // Clear auto filter on table srcTab
        srcTab.getAutoFilter().clearCriteria();
        // Apply checked items filter on table srcTab column Col5
        srcTab.getColumnById(FILTER_COLUMN_INDEX).getFilter().applyValuesFilter([FILTER_VALUE]);

        const filterRange = srcTab.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getSpecialCells(ExcelScript.SpecialCellType.visible);
        if (filterRange) {
            let anchorCell = desTab.getColumnById(1).getRange().getLastCell()
            if (anchorCell.getValue()) {
                // move to next line if not-blank
                anchorCell = anchorCell.getOffsetRange(1, 0)
            }
            anchorCell.copyFrom(filterRange);
            // Update formula
            desTab.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().replaceAll(`${SOURCE_TABLE_NAME}[`, "[", { completeMatch: false, matchCase: false });
            // Get range address
            const rangeList: string[] = filterRange.getAddress().split(",");

        // Remove data rows from source table
            for (let i = rangeList.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                let areaRange = srcTab.getWorksheet().getRange(rangeList[i]);
                areaRange.getEntireRow().delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up);
            }
            
            srcTab.getAutoFilter().clearCriteria();

            // Restore original filters
            Object.keys(originalTableFilters).forEach((columnName: string) => {
                const filterCriteria = originalTableFilters[columnName];
                if (filterCriteria) {
                    srcTab.getColumnByName(columnName).getFilter().apply(filterCriteria);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log("No data in filtered source table")
        }
    }
    // Re-hide the columns that were initially hidden in the source table
    hiddenSourceColumns.forEach(index => {
        sourceRange.getColumn(index).getEntireColumn().setColumnHidden(true);
    });

    // Re-hide the columns that were initially hidden in the target table
    hiddenTargetColumns.forEach(index => {
        targetRange.getColumn(index).getEntireColumn().setColumnHidden(true);
    });
}
    

